# Batch Process images on AWS S3 using SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, batch-processing, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS EC2 for my web application that watermark images, resizes them in 5 different sizes and uploads them to AWS S3 along with original Image.

Now I want to process original images again to add a new watermark and make new sizes.I have a million images on S3 and I am confused how to process them.I have researched google and read many blogs. Only I found that I can use SQS for this but I don't know how it will work and how to configure it.

I want this to be done on very less time.
How should I proceed further ?

Comment: What have you already tried, and what didn't work? SQS can trigger an event when e.g. a new image is saved, which would handle all future images. But you would still need to handle existing images somehow.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have handled new images but I am concerned about the 1 million images that are already on s3 bucket.
I want to re-process them all

Comment: Personally I recommend using Thumbor, it will handle all of this for you and resize images on demand. If you want to pre-process all the existing images, E. J. Brennan's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

SQS could be used to schedule the work for you, but would only be helpful if you planned on spinning up several instances to do the actual conversions. SQS has nothing to do with the actual image conversions - only the parceling out of the tasks.

If you are only going to use just one EC2 instance (make it as big and fast as you can afford), and just let it crunch thru the million files as fast as it can - since this is a one-time effort, this will be your easiest option if it will complete fast enough for you.

If you are going to use a fleet of EC2 instances to do the work, then install your custom software (that does the conversions) on each of the machines, add a new piece of (probably custom) software that will poll the sqs queue asking for 'work to do', and then once the instances are up and running, load the SQS queue with the details of each image you need processed; one message per file.

Your fleet of machines will poll the queue, get one (or more) messages to process (the message should contain among other things the S3 file location), and let it process the image and re-upload to s3. When an image is done, the ec2 instance deletes that message from the queue and asks for another message to process.

What SQS does for you, in this situation, is to provide a 'queue' of messages to be processed and let lots and lots of consumers 1) ask for work to do, and 2) tell sqs to delete the message when the work is done and 3) try its best to make sure that the same message is not sent to more than one machine (it happens rarely). Using SQS is an effecient way to have a fleet of machines working on the same queue, without worrying about how to split up the work amongst them.

But, as I said, in your case, since this is a one-time conversion effort, the using of a queue may or may not be warranted - you could let one machine do all the work, if you think it could run fast enough, or split up the work to be done manually (i.e. machine 'A' takes all files created in month1, machine 'B' does all the files create in month2 etc - any method you have to split up the work amongst the machines would work as well; SQS is just one method.